# Running an update query makes an entry unfindable by other queries || Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, sql-update

My update query in question changes all entries labeled "HA" to the name of a person assigned to that entry. The UpdateTo is connected to a Sales rep table and the query requires you to input the sales rep entry number in order to update the main table sales rep column. In the main table the choice of Sales rep is a combo box.

This part works fine, it is when I use another query that is supposed to pull all entries related to a selected sales rep that draws the issue.

Any entry that I have changed manually or with an update query becomes unfindable to Select queries and search functions.

Here's the SQL for the update query, (company names changed for privacy):

```
UPDATE Invoices SET Invoices.SalesRep = [SalesReps].[SalesRep]
WHERE 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyA")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyB")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyC")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyD")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyE")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyF")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyG")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyH")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyI") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Invoice Number]) Like "AN*")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyI") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Invoice Number]) Like "ME*")) OR 
    (((Invoices.SalesRep)="HA") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Customer Name])="CompanyH") AND 
    ((Invoices.[Invoice Number]) Like "ME*"));
```

And the SQL for the Select query:

```
SELECT
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Customer Name], 
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Invoice Date],
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Invoice Number],
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Invoice Amount],
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Out Date],
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[In Date],
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].SalesRep
FROM [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ]
WHERE 
    ((([Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Customer Name])=[Enter Customer Name]) AND 
    (([Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Invoice Number]) Like [Enter 2-Letter Department] & "*") AND 
    (([Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Out Date])>=[Start Date] And 
    ([Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Out Date])<=[End Date]) AND 
    (([Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[In Date]) Is Null) AND 
    (([Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].SalesRep)=[Enter SalesRep Name]))
ORDER BY 
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Invoice Date], 
    [Q-ALL UNSIGNED Invoices SIGREQ].[Invoice Number];
```

I have tried changing the value to all options, manually caning the names, copy-pasting the entry from an entry that is findable, and deleting and reentering the entire entry.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but you may find it useful nonetheless: `WHERE Invoices.SalesRep = 'HA' AND Invoices.[Customer Name] IN ('CompanyA','CompanyB','etc')`  Basically, your SQL can be simpler with `IN()` instead of all those `OR` conditions.

Comment: Example would be better if you did not repeat "Company" - use fake names like ABC, DEF, etc. The UPDATE does not make sense. How does the UPDATE know which SalesRep to pull from SalesReps table? Advise not to build LOOKUP fields in table. Since SalesRep parameter shows text, I presume field is text type and you are not using autonumber ID as PK/FK link.

Comment: @June7 The UPDATE asks for a Sales rep corresponding entry number. So for this one you'd put in '14' and it would update with the 14th entry on the SalesReps Table in the Sales Rep column. I do not believe I have a LOOKUP field in the table

Comment: "***In the main table the choice of Sales rep is a combo box.***" - that sounds like a lookup in table. Are you saying this `= [SalesReps].[SalesRep]` will trigger a user popup prompt? You show SalesRep criteria as alpha - so why would you enter `14` into prompt? I NEVER use popup prompts in query - cannot validate input. Better to reference control on form for user input. But I avoid dynamic parameters in query as much as possible and prefer to use VBA to build criteria and apply to form or report.

Comment: Names make very poor unique identifiers. Should save ID's as primary/foreign keys and search on those instead. So is SalesRep field storing a name or ID?

Comment: Yes, it triggers a popup prompt. The name of the rep is in the 14th slot in the column so it updates  "HA" with the name of the 14th rep. Sales Rep field is names. I am not familiar with saving ID's as primary/foreign keys.

Comment: @SterlingDrake Paste this highlighted text into the Access Immediate window and press Enter: `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("Invoices").Fields("SalesRep").Type` What number does Access show you in response?  (You can use Ctrl+g to go to the Immediate window.)

Comment: And if you do `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("Invoices").Fields("SalesRep").Properties("RowSourceType").Value`, does Access respond *"Property not found"* or something else?

Comment: Using a number type field (or GUID) as primary key and then saving that value as foreign key in related tables is basic database concept. In Access, this is what the Autonumber field type is intended for. If SalesRep field has settings for combobox in table, then it might display names but actually save ID. Would need to know property settings for this combobox.

Comment: @HansUp Shows 10, then Table/Query.

Comment: @June7 Display Control - Combo Box; Row Source Type - Table/Query; Row Source - SELECT SalesReps.ID, SalesReps.SalesRep FROM SalesReps; Limit to list - Yes; Allow multiple Values - No; Allow Value List edits - Yes

Comment: `Invoices.SalesRep` is a lookup field. The field stores one value but displays a different value. If you run your `UPDATE` and enter 14 as the requested value, do you then see the unfindable rows if you run this query? `SELECT i.* FROM Invoices AS i WHERE i.SalesRep = '14'`